# What software is used for blog.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, blog

Just as the title states; I found it odd that it isn't mentioned in the question ["Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network).

Comment: It's just WordPress

Comment: @random: Source?  Also, shouldn't it really be an answer if it is an authoritative answer and then I'd accept it?

Comment: It's [Wordpress](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-login.php), the theme is based on [ZimpleZa](http://www.themesguru.com/themepreview/ZimpleZa/). I figured out the theme simply by viewing the page source.

Comment: @Tim Post: You know, a server can serve up anything =)  You can blame [skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) for my desiring an answer from the horse's mouth.  [@yydl answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93957/what-software-is-used-for-blog-stackexchange-com/93958#93958) satisfies this requirement, IMO.

Comment: @casperOne - I don't think you'll see this one on Mythbusters ... sorry :P

Comment: @Tim Post: Agreed, not meant to give you or @random a hard time, I just think it's important on the meta sites to have hard references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It runs [WordPress on Linux](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/blog-outage-backup-policies/).

> Anyway, we were able to piece together a backup from different sources, and I took this opportunity to move the blog from WordPress on Windows (which has been incredibly quirky) to WordPress on Linux.